# Scala Ordering by multiple values

Tags: scala

I am trying to use `Ordering[T]` with multiple types.

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

Person("Alice", 20)
Person("Bob", 40)
Person("Charlie", 30)

object PersonOrdering extends Ordering[Person] {
  def compare(a:Person, b:Person) =
    a.age compare b.age
}
```

**How do I sort by both name and age?**

The collection needs to remain sorted with updates.

Answer (score 9):

Order by the tuple of name and age.

Also, it's generally easier to call `Ordering.by` rather than extend `Ordering` yourself.

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

implicit val personOrdering: Ordering[Person] =
  Ordering.by(p => (p.name, p.age))

Seq(Person("a", 2), Person("b", 1), Person("a", 1)).sorted
// Seq[Person] = List(Person(a,1), Person(a,2), Person(b,1))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a tuple and sort that:

```
val people = List(
Person("Alice", 20),
Person("Bob", 40),
Person("Charlie", 30)
)

people.orderBy(x => (x.name,x.age))
```

In case of extending `Ordering` should be the same, make a tuple and compare them