# maxBy() multiple attributes of objects in List()

Tags: scala, implicit, maxby

Say I have a list of books

```
val books = List(Book)
```

where `Book(bookID: String, bookName: String)` and a map

```
val scores = Map(bookID -> score:float)
```

I would like to get the book with the highest `score` first, then alphabetically by `bookName`

Getting the book with the highest rated score is rather simple:

```
val bestBook = books.maxBy(x => score(x.bookID))
```

But in case of multiple books with the same score I would then like to sort by the `bookName`. I'm not sure how to add a second criterion to `maxBy`? I suppose I can `maxBy()` score first, then I retrieve the score of `bestBook`, and filter `books` with the max score, then `minBy()` the `bookName`?

But that seems really cumbersome, is there a more efficient way of doing this? I've seen previous threads that does something similar with the `Ordering` implicit: [Scala Ordering by multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778715/scala-ordering-by-multiple-values), but I couldn't figure out how to define `Ordering` in this context.

Answer (score 3):

Using `maxBy` by both the higher score (thanks to the `-` on the score) and the name:

```scala
books
  .maxBy(b => (-score(b.bookId), b.name))
```

The same ordering on tuple can be used for sorting if needed.

Comment: ah I didn't think of that, but in terms of performance, isn't sortBy going to be O(nlog n) while maxBy is O(n) (i think?)

Comment: Right, you can use the same approach with `maxBy` on a tuple.

Comment: Don't recommend sort for a simple max operation.

Comment: Sure, edited the post :)